# Supported CSS-GRID browser on Sony Android tv

Tags: android, css, css-grid, android-tv, sony

I created a web application dashboard which looks totally fine on the browser on the pc. Now what I would like to do is show this application 24/7 on a Sony Android tv with model number (BRAVIA 2017, android v. 7.0 kernel version 3.10.79).

Chrome natively isn't supported so I tried installing it using an APK. The thing is it the application doesn't look good due to the fact that this browser has a window width of about a 1000px and a height of 417 pixels. I tried downscaling in Chrome settings on the tv but it doesnt work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could try or what other browsers are supported with a nice viewport width and height?

The native build in browser does **not** support css-grid

**EDIT:**
The default browser is called Vewd

Answer (score 0):

It's a fact that some browsers ignore CSS they don't understand. If a browser which does not support CSS Grid comes across something it doesn't know, it throws that line away and continues.

Maybe you can use some old CSS like `float`,

or something to provide a grid type of layout, like

`display: table-cell` :)

Comment: thanks for your reply but I specificly want to use css-grids